# How to add pybind11 to python file?

Tags: python, pybind11, openpose

I am using using openpose for my project and I have setup everything required but stuck with this pybind11 error

I am running python webcam.py command

```
Starting OpenPose Python Wrapper...
Auto-detecting all available GPUs... Detected 1 GPU(s), using 1 of them starting at GPU 0.
(540, 960, 3)
Wait for connection...
Client Info:  <socket.socket fd=2272, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 9000), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 61761)> ('127.0.0.1', 61761)
emplaceAndPop(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: pyopenpose.WrapperPython, arg0: std::vector<std::shared_ptr<op::Datum>,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<op::Datum> > >) -> bool

Invoked with: <pyopenpose.WrapperPython object at 0x000001F2386CCA30>, [<pyopenpose.Datum object at 0x000001F2364714B0>]

Did you forget to `#include <pybind11/stl.h>`? Or <pybind11/complex.h>,
<pybind11/functional.h>, <pybind11/chrono.h>, etc. Some automatic
conversions are optional and require extra headers to be included
when compiling your pybind11 module.
```

Please help me resolve this error, I am using windows?

Comment: The Python wrapper on the C++ code is broken, not your script

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, can you help me how to resolve this?

Comment: To help you resolve this, we would need to see the C++ code